# Qt Installation stuck with 'Unknown Time Remaining' and doesn't proceed

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-installer

I get an 'Unknown time remaining error' when trying to install Qt 64 bit version on my Windows 10 machine, and the download stuck and doesn't proceed further as shown in the screenshot below [qt_installation_stuck_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRAVr.png).

How do i continue downloading?

Comment: You need to be more specific, can you tell what installer you are using and on which machine and maybe screenshot will try to get attention to those who has noticed similar problem.

Comment: I am using the QT online installer on windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: I cant be of much help other than suggesting to try Offline installer. Go to this [link](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) and select the Windows Host Offline Installers as per your requirement and see if that helps.

Comment: when a connection error occurs while downloading, the installer displays a message box where you can click *Try Again* when your internet connection is Okay again. For me,  the button resumed the download from the point it stopped.

Comment: Hello i have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Is this your own PC or a company one? - are there any policies that might stop you (place I work at kills downloads > 100mb)? - Alternatively you could try the offline installer: https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-5 (if you still can't download it on this pc, try another and copy it across....)

Comment: This is my own pc and there are no restrictions on my bandwidth. I can download other stuff without any problem.Anyways, does the offline installer include all the features like the online installer?

Comment: As far as I know, Features wise there should not be any difference in using Online installers vs Offline installers. As name suggests Online installers has got a framework to take your Qt account credential and find if you have any commercial license so on. So you can go ahead and try offline installer and see if you can get it working first.